# Change value of a button in a form

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using an eCommerce module. In a 'view cart' node, there is a 'remove' button so users can remove items they no longer wish to purchase, however, instead of the 'remove' value on each button, I'd like to have a simple icon and no text, how would I go about making this change? I understand it would probably be a form alter function in the template.php file, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can done it in form_alter . first need to know what is your button name in $form in form_alter, I suggest you `print_r` or `var_dump` `$form` and found your button (buttons usually are in `#actions`) . after it I suggest you handle your job with add a `css class or id` to your button and with css style it .

```
function yourcustom_form_alter(&$form,$form_state) {
  $form['actions]['yourbuttonname']['#value'] ='';
   $form['actions]['yourbuttonname']['#attributes'] =array('class'=>array('yourcssclass'));
}
```